# How to concatenate a Hash to URL parameters?

Tags: ruby, url

a quick Ruby question for you:

```
params = {:q => "A query",:foo => "bar",:nasty => "Schrödinger's cat"}
p do_it(params)
=> q=A%20query&foo=bar&nasty=Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s+cat
```

(I think ö encodes like that, excuse me if its wrong) Is there a simpler way to do this than the following?:

```
def do_it(params)
  out = []
  params.each_pair{|key,val|
    out.push "#{CGI.escape(key.to_s)}=#{CGI.escape(val)}"
  }
  out.join("&")
end
```

I'm not looking to start a war over the 'best' way to do this - its just this method seems very kludgey and un-ruby like! Any tips?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a shorter and more efficient method.

```
def parameterize(params)
  URI.escape(params.collect{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&'))
end
```

Comment: Be sure to use this with `URI.escape` and not `CGI.escape` because the latter will turn that `=` into `%3D`.

Answer (score 6):

use .to_param

```
params = {:q => "A query",:foo => "bar",:nasty => "Schrödinger's cat"}

params.to_param 
=> "foo=bar&nasty=Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s+cat&q=A+query"
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails does this for you.

```
params = {:ids => [1,2], :query => 'cheese'}
out = ActionController::Routing::Route.new.build_query_string(params)
=> "?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&query=cheese"
```

which decoded would be:  "?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&query=cheese"

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a little bit simpler using [`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003127):

```
def do_it(params)
  params.collect do |key,val|
    "#{CGI.escape(key.to_s)}=#{CGI.escape(val)}"
  end.join('&')
end
```

I don't know how much more you can simplify it than that.  Also, note that `CGI.escape` will converts spaces into `+`, not `%20`.  If you really want `%20`, use `URI.escape` instead (you'll have to `require 'uri'`, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is very "un-ruby-like" code.  Although it's not much better, I think requestify() may be what you want:

http://www.koders.com/ruby/fid4B642EE4A494A744ACC920A1BE72CFE66D1D2B97.aspx?s=cgi#L291

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try following

```
def to_query(key)
  "#{CGI.escape(key.to_s)}=#{CGI.escape(to_param.to_s)}"
end
```

copied from [rails documentation](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/27dbc27c4174974a318145d2dc6512457ea37241/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/conversions.rb#L11). Do not forget to read the comments above the method definition.